# Write variable sheets from python to excel

Tags: python, xlwt

I want to write 250 sheets in Excel with the sheet number as variable. Since then I can be specific which output I want on wich sheet. I tried

```
from xlwt import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
for i in range(250):
    sheeti = wb.add_sheet('Sheet i')
```

Which gives me logically the error that the worksheet name is duplicated. This is ofcourse because every sheet is now called 'Sheet i'.

Moreover, if I want to write the sheet with the following code

```
 sheeti.write
```

It gives me that sheeti is not defined.

I can not figure out the solution to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is now in my loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're literally naming each sheet 'sheet i'. What you want is 'sheet ' + str(i), or something equivalent.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? http://xlwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

If you correctly call wb.add_sheet() which you should do now, it should return a Workbook object and sheeti should be defined. It's important you then make calls to sheeti **within** the scope of the for loop.